Unable to see related attributes to an Individual in Data Cloud segmentation
Use Case: I am using Accts to represent businesses and want to segment Individuals based on Acct and Contact Attributes.
Mappings: I have an external ID on both Contact and Acct. I have mapped Contact ID and Account ID to PartyIdentification.Party, and mapped that external ID to PartyIdentification.IdentificationNumber. Salesforce confirmed that this is the mapping. Account and Contact are related to the data model. Party Identification is related by default to Individual, and the ID resolution is run correctly.
Problem: I don't see Account or Contact in the related attributes list in segmentation. I don't understand which relationships or mappings are missing/incorrect. I also see no other related objects, like Opportunity and Campaign Member.



